# Can an element have both an id and a class?

Tags: html, css, class

pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: because i'm a beginner. why not?
i got a perfect answer here that i couldn't find in w3schools, htmldog, or css discuss. and in less than 5 min.

Comment: Honestly you could have find out that yourself. Creating a CSS file and testing it should not be too difficult. Also google for `html element class id` reveals this http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2 which gives some examples....

Comment: alright, i didn't actually write a css file to see if it would work. i've had problems with css lately that have shown me that there are a lot of wrinkles to it, and that right now for a lot of things it's better to ask, because i really don't know much.  why so heavy?

Comment: And you help others searching on the topic too: +1 from mee, good question.

Comment: While yes, you could have easily figured out if it was possible, the question has validity when the meta data is taken into account. For example, Nick's answer that states that the ID must be unique. It's interesting, because there are often holes in people's knowledge. Many who are self-taught have never used a Queue or Stack... as they learn from doing before discovering.

Comment: Ignore the snobs briligg.  We welcome all levels here!

Comment: I like the question. Almost all beginner level HTML examples show an HTML element having either a Class or an ID applied, exclusively-- not in combo.

Answer (score 146, accepted):

Yes, an element can have one ID (which must be unique!) and multiple classes at the same time. To have multiple classes, use a space between them, here's an example:

```
<div id="myID" class="class1 class2 class3">Content</div>
```

Comment: I'm giving you an upvote, without further explanations for why I'm doing so.

Comment: Does it matter which order you set the id and class? Or can I set the class first and then id?

Answer (score 13):

I would like to add that if you add both ID and a class that contradict each other, the ID will have higher priority.

For example:

CSS:

```
.par_color{
    color:red;
}

#par_color{
    color:blue;
}
```

HTML:

```
<section id="par_color" class="par_color">Some txt</section>
```

Some txt string will be shown in blue and not in red.

Comment: ...Because id has higher selectivity than class.

Answer (score 7):

Yes. Self explanatory.

Additionally, it's common to have more than one class IE -

```
<div class="oneClass andAnother"></div>
```

but only one ID per element, and each ID should only be used once per HTML page.

Comment: Where's the `id` attribute..?

Answer (score 6):

Yes.

```
<div id="main" class="rounded">
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

In short, yes. Usually the class would be for styling and the id to allow direct manipulation by scripts.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can add id and class as well as a class and a id

for a class and a id`<h1 id="orange-text" class="pink-text blue-text">Hello World!</h1>`
***for two classes***
`<h1 class="orange-text" class="pink-text blue-text">Hello World!</h1>`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. But note that Id's must be unique within your html file, while classes can be used in multiples elements.

```
<div class="examples" id="example1">text example</div>
```